# macOS 10.14.3: External Drive Mounts Fine, but Not with Shell Script

Tags: shell, macos-mojave

< 3.5 GHz, 6-Core Mac Pro (MacPro6,1) with 16GB RAM and D700 GPUs, running macOS 10.14.3 >

Greetings, folks!

I just erased my internal boot drive, and upgraded from Mac OS 10.10.5 to macOS 10.14.3.

;-)

I have a backup drive (diskutil list appended below my sig.) that will mount just fine it I turn it on, but if I unmount the drive, using either the Finder or Terminal, Terminal cannot re-mount it. Here’s the two lines from Terminal:

```
ME$ diskutil mountDisk disk2
One or more volume(s) failed to mount
```

(I also cannot get into the Recovery volume when booting, using cmd-r)

Any suggestions?

Blessings and thank you!

Richard Fairbanks

————

Here is Terminal’s list of volumes:

```
ME$ diskutil list

/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.1 GB   disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +500.1 GB   disk1
                           Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume Cupid                   376.9 GB   disk1s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.5 MB    disk1s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.0 MB   disk1s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk1s4

/dev/disk2 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *4.0 TB     disk2
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk2s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Cupid Clone             500.0 GB   disk2s2
   3:                  Apple_HFS OS X 1                  40.0 GB    disk2s3
   4:                 Apple_APFS Container disk3         40.1 GB    disk2s4
   5:                  Apple_HFS Applications            100.0 GB   disk2s5
   6:                  Apple_HFS ME                      1000.0 GB  disk2s6
   7:                  Apple_HFS Miscellaneous           2.3 TB     disk2s7

/dev/disk3 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +40.1 GB    disk3
                           Physical Store disk2s4
   1:                APFS Volume macOS Mojave            25.3 GB    disk3s1
   2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 44.4 MB    disk3s2
   3:                APFS Volume Recovery                517.0 MB   disk3s3
   4:                APFS Volume VM                      8.6 GB     disk3s4
```

Comment: Hello Richard! This really isn't a programming question and you might have better luck if you ask on http://askdifferent.com (StackExchange's Apple IT / superuser site) or http://superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

diskutil mountDisk attempts to mount all mountable volumes on every partition. From the internal docs:

> "Attempt to mount the directly-mountable volumes on all of a whole disk's partitions. However, virtual volumes which are implied by e.g. Core Storage Physical Volumes, AppleRAID Members, etc. are not handled."

And given this error:

> One or more volume(s) failed to mount

I would assume one of the volumes fails to mount, halting the entire process - probably one of the first ones, like the EFI partition.

Funnily enough, it looks like I get the same failure on my machine (10.14 as well) when diskutil attempts to mount the EFI partition without admin privileges (using diskutil mount diskxs1 without sudo fails as well). You should be able to see a log for this in Console.app when you attempt to run the command.
It might be that this was overlooked more gracefully, mounted read-only, or was a security issue in earlier OSes, and the upgrade to 10.14 brought in the change.

Try mounting them individually using

> diskutil mount disk2s2
>
> diskutil mount disk2s3
>
> etc ....

or escalating privileges with sudo if it's a one-off as a work around.

If the EFI partition is not the issue, I would still suspect a single volume is causing the problem, so mount them separately, one-by-one and run a fsck / firstaid / diskwarrior etc. to confirm each disk is functional and mountable

Hope it helps,

-Al